# Can we post our own ads in Android apps? Is that possible

Tags: android

i want to display some images (changes frequently) as ads in my own app by using coding in app (without registering in Admob sites etc…)is this possible?

Actually, i don’t have knowledge in coding, but i want to develop one app with the help of any android developer

Comment: yes, you can. You are not limited with google ADS.

Comment: So, i can post my own images as ads in my app without registering in any mobile ad websites, right?

Comment: yes, right, you can show any images in your app, and google does not care unless they are legal. There is no difference for google if the image is advertisement, a cat photo, or an element of UI.